# Gap Inserted Between Div Rows

Tags: css, html

I have a simple row listing certain funding opportunities. I'm confused to a behaviour that is occurring with the CSS/HTML code where there will be a gap between entries on the list if I don't use separate classes. 
For example, the below picture indicates what happens when I use:

```
<div class="panel-inside">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Funding Opportunity 1</div>
        <div class="label-date">Sep. 16, 2012</div>
    </div>
    <div class="listSeparator"></div> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Funding Opportunity 2</div>
        <div class="label-date">Dec. 2, 2012</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

However if I close each **"panel-inside"** class then the result is different.

```
<div class="panel-inside">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Funding Opportunity 1</div>
        <div class="label-date">Sep. 16, 2012</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="listSeparator"></div> 
<div class="panel-inside">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Funding Opportunity 2</div>
        <div class="label-date">Dec. 2, 2012</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I need the formatting to be like the second picture, but I don't understand why I have to close each "panel-inside" class. Shouldn't that div be the 'container' for rows? I think the reason the gap is there is because the second row starts where the text from the one before it left off, but I have no idea how to fix this. I've included the CSS code below with border colour outlining to help differentiate the elements. Thanks for any help!

```
.panel-inside { 
    border: 3px dotted purple;
    border-left: 2px solid #D6D3D6;
    border-right: 2px solid #D6D3D6;
    background: white;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    overflow:auto;
    border-radius:7px;
} 

.row                                   
{
    height: 40px;      
    width:100%;        
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.label                               
{
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    font-family: BBAlpha Sans;
    font-size: 15pt;
    display:inline;    
    float:left;
    line-height:40px; 
    margin-left:5px;   
}

.label-date
{
    border: 1px dotted black;
    font-family: BBAlpha Sans;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color:#686868;
    display:inline;    
    float:right;
    line-height:40px; 
    margin-right:7px;  
}

.listSeparator                
{
    border-bottom: solid 1px Silver;
}
```

Comment: what browser are you using? I've tried it in IE and chrome and it looks just like in the picture (without adding the separator div and without closing and reopening the div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try modifying the listSeparator class like so:

```
.listSeparator                
{
    border-bottom: solid 1px Silver;
    clear:both;
}
```

This happens because you don't clearfix the .row class properly, but the outside extra div serves as a partial resetter.

Answer (score 2):

Seriously - when you have tabular data and a tabular structure - use tables... far more robust and crossbrowser compatible.

Optionally - add `overflow:auto;` to your `.row` OR `clear:both;`to `.listSeparator`, this should solve the issue.

edit: you can omit the height when using `overflow` and also omit the `.listSeparator` (by adding the border to `.row`).

Comment: I would +1 for the recommendation but that should be a comment since it's not an answer really.

Comment: this depends - when he switches to tables, this would solve his issue, but i added another solution for his original problem;)

Comment: Thanks Christoph and Mihalis, this works. From the advice I think I'll give the table thing some thought, it would make things a lot easier. I'm still in the learning stages, but again thank you this really does help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution without closing class="panel-inside" class for every row.

HTML is similar as first condition but one difference -

```
<div class="listSeparator">&nbsp;</div>
```

Css:

```
.listSeparator { border-bottom: solid 1px Silver; clear:both;}
```

Clear allows floated elements occuring earlier in the document to float along its sides.
So by using clear:both means that your div will shifted in the end of other floating elements beside your div.

http://www.free-scripts.net/html_tutorial/css/properties/classify/clear.htm

http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html